# Java 8: store and retrieve data in form of a data table

Tags: java, datatable, java-8, store

I'd like store data in form of a data table, which looks like this:

```
+--------+-------+-----+-----+
|        |   s1  |  s2 |  s3 |
+--------+-------+-----+-----+
|   c1   |   5   |  7  |  7  |
+--------+-------+-----+-----+
|   c2   |   1   |  6  |  9  |
+--------+-------+-----+-----+
|   c3   |   0   |  9  |  6  |
+--------+-------+-----+-----+
```

What is a good way to store this in java, so that I can retrieve the data by their keys.

I need a method which looks like this:

```
public int getData(String row, String column);

// Example:
int i = getData("c1", "s1") // Would return 5
```

Comment: All three columns are called s1?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @pringi no they are all different, thx for the input

Comment: You can have a look at Google guava's [Table](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#table)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Guava

https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#table

```
Table<String, String, Integer> records = HashBasedTable.create();
records.put("s1","c1",5);
records.put("s3", "c3", 6);

Integer val = records.get("s1","c1"); // val = 5
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve that is with a data structure like this:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> map;
```

Answer (score 0):

Either a two dimensional Map

```
Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> map;

public int getData(String row, String column) {
    return map.get(row).get(column); // can lead to NullPointerException
}
```

or you can use a two dimensional array:

```
int[][] array = new int[10][12];

public int getData(String row, String column) {
    int x = ...; // get index from string
    int y = ...; // get index from string
    return array[x][y];
}
```

The second approach is only viable if the structure of the table does not change too often and if you can parse the index out of the strings.